# Task Scheduler shared hosting

Tags: php, perl, email

I am using a shared host that which doesn't support CRON/TaskScheduler (it is a windows Godaddy server).

I need to search on email server for new emails on each 1 hour, I have the script on PHP.

Can I use `PERL` to emulate a task on certain times, or is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Just find a different hosting provider. You can probably even find a VPS for under $50/yr if you look hard enough.

Comment: @tdammers This is strictly a programming related question. I just want to know the possibilities.

Comment: You have a problem. Programming is not the solution to your problem. Hence I suggested a non-programming solution. Do with it what you want.

Comment: Yep. If Cron is not supported then programming can hardly help you. Asking you to look into Celery might be overkill.

Comment: @tdammers You are misunderstanding me. I just want to know the ability of PERL , i can have a different host. But its not the actual scenario. Does PERL can do this in some ways ? ex : a sleep of 1 hour ...

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a little "outside the box", but you could expose your code as a channel If This Then That (https://ifttt.com/) understands (for instance, an RSS feed), and then create a recipe that starts on a timer, and reads your "feed", kicking off your code?

Comment: +1, this is the modern version of "write a web service. Then have your home PC hit that web service on a scheduled basis."